# Gmail move mail delivery errors to separate folder

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have an installation of PHPBB3, and it sends mail from my Gmail address to users.  However, I just got an influx of spambots with fake addresses that bounce.

How do I tell Gmail to move these errors to a different mail folder or delete them?  They keep showing up in my inbox.  I think part of the problem might be that the errors are replies to the original automatic message, so it places them in my inbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all these messages have common pattern, like the same originating address or the same/similar subject, then you can solve it by creating a custom filter and specifying a folder to move emails to.

For additional info on creating filters read [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en).

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer after a message gets sorted into the folder I setup.  If the spambots don't trigger one soon, I'll use a fake address of my own to get the same result.